# Dynamic form field in generic view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to show an extra captcha field after several unsuccessful attempts to send a form.

It is [pretty easy](http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/) while dealing with an ordinary form, but how can one achieve it in a generic view?

```
# models.py

class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = MyForm
    model = MyModel

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if show_captcha:
            form = MyForm(form, captcha=True)
            return self.form_invalid(form)

# forms.py

class MyForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        captcha = kwargs.pop('captcha', None)
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if captcha:
            self.fields['captcha'] = ReCaptchaField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['myfield']
```

**EDIT:**

I updated my code. The error I get is:

`'MyForm' object has no attribute 'get'`

It points to my template, to line:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not any different if you're using a generic view. You just need to override the correct method: in this case, [`get_form_kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) would be a good bet, as this returns the keyword arguments to pass to the form instantiation. So in that method you just need to add your extra parameter to whatever is returned by the superclass method.